# mysql french documentation

Tags: mysql, documentation

I am not able to find a translation for Mysql documentation

> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/

I read English quite well, but it is not the case for all my colleagues.

Comment: What exactly do you expect from this question? It's not like we're going to translate all the docs in an answer here.

Comment: Well, you can use Google Translate and put in the web site: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/  (Of course, I do not vouch for the quality of computerized translation, but it may help those who struggle with the English.)

Comment: I expect someone know there is a translation somewhere, maybe a community project or something like that. I expect help from another developer, if such translation exists. If it does note, I don't think it's a reason to downvote my question. Maybe dba is not the right website to ask this... Sorry, I have just understand your "off-topic" mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is for MySQL 5.0 
http://downloads.mysql.com/docs/refman-5.0-fr.a4.pdf

It's not completely new, but it might be helpful.

Comment: Here's the full list of doc archives for 5.0, too: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-archive.html